# CoreData: deleteObject faults on relationships when nil

Tags: objective-c, core-data, entity-relationship

We have a project that has two one to many relationships. We encounter a core data fault when we try to delete the parent object. This ONLY happens if the child relationships are empty. So for example:

A project has many to-dos and messages. If we create a project and add a message and a to-do to it, and subsequently call deleteObject on the managedObjectContext we have no problem. BUT if we create a new project and then try to call deleteObject without ever creating any to-do's or messages we run into a relationship fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We resolved this by changing the inverse relationship's delete rule from nullify to no-action. This makes sense since this relationship is optional.

Comment: Hit the checkmark next to this answer so the system shows it as answered.

Comment: No need to be a wiseguy I can't accept my own answer for another 23 hours.

Comment: But won't you now end up with orphaned to-do's and messages when you delete a project that does have them?

Comment: @trapper - yes you would. We had to perform this check manually in our code to do the house keeping. That being said this was several years ago. We've been using Realm for the past two years and loving it. Again you have to check for this sort of thing manually in Realm as well.